# Why a Muslim is using things invented by Christians, Jews like mobile phones, a bunch of medicines, Facebook, whatsapp and many more? Is it allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, non-muslim

We as a Muslim, we don't celebrate birthdays and things like that which is created by non-Muslims. But on the other hand, we use Mobiles, laptops, eating products, medicines, trains, and many more daily life things which is also created by non Muslims. Can anyone explain me the reason behind it? Why this partial boycott?

Answer (score 1):

The default ruling in Islamic law, in regards to mundane things that aren't considered religious custom/duties, is that everything is permissible by default. We only forbid actions when there is clear evidence showing that we need to do so.

Regarding birthdays, there are evidences that explicitly mention celebrating the non-believer's festivals and that such is to be avoided, which many consider applicable to the celebration of birthdays as well. However, that evidence doesn't say anything about the usage of mundane items, whether or not they're created by the non-believers.

If your contention is that using mobiles, laptops, trains, etc is or should be forbidden, the onus is on you to show evidence that that's the case, not on Islamic law to prove that it's not.